# Get a ArrayList containing the union of two different sized arraylist of some object type

Tags: java, object, comparison, for-loop, arraylist

I have a bean class containing two variables Title and ID.

```
public class Bean(){
    private String title;
    private String ID;
}
```

I also have two arraylists of type Bean - ArrayList firstList and ArrayList secondList. Both have different number of Bean elements in them i.e. the size for the two arraylist is different and they can be huge in size. Some of the Bean elements present in them may contain same IDs.

Now I have a different bean class MainBean containing three variables

```
public class Mainbean(){
    private String firstTitle;
    private String secondTitle;
    private String ID;
}
```

I need to create a new ArrayList of type MainBean based on values from the above two arraylist - ArrayList finalList.

While comparing the above two arraylist (firstList and secondList), the following needs to be kept in mind -

1) First condition - If same ID is present in both the lists, then the new ArrayList finalList will have the ID populated and the firstTitle from the firstList and the secondTitle from the secondList.

2) If an ID from firstList is not present in secondList, the finalList will have the ID and firstTitle from firstList while the secondTitle will be null.

3) If an ID from secondList is not present in firstList, the finalList will have the ID and secondTitle from secondList while the firstTitle will be null.

Please help me form such a finalList arraylist.

Comment: I am looking for a java code here.Please help.

Answer (score 2):

To do it effectively, you need to use a HashMap.

```
ArrayList<Mainbean> result = new ArrayList<Mainbean>();
HashMap<String, Mainbean> bean_by_id = new HashMap<String, Mainbean>();

// first list: all are new element
for(Bean b : firstList)
{
    // if you do not have constructor (ID, title1, title2):
    Mainbean mb = new Mainbean(){{ this.ID = b.ID; this.firstTitle = b.title; }};
    result.add(mb);
    bean_by_id.put(mb.ID, mb);
}

for(Bean b : secondList)
{
    Mainbean mb = bean_by_id.get(b.ID);
    if (mb==null)
    {
        mb = new Mainbean(){{ this.ID = b.ID; this.secondTitle = b.title; }};
        result.add(mb);
    }
    else mb.secondTitle = b.title;
}
```

Comment: in the 2nd for, shouldn't that bean_by_ad.get() accept b.ID instead of mb.ID? nice solution btw, it's O(m + n), much faster than mine :)

Comment: Thanks for signaling the problem.

Comment: Hi LD, Thanks for ur reply. But I just wanted to ask you in the second loop, u have written result.add(mb) will this not add two entries in the arraylist for the same ID (for different Id its fine)?

Comment: I have modified ur code this way, please advise will this be affected in case the initial arraylists are huge in size and performance-wise how it is. I dont add the MainBeans in the result arraylist in the two for loops and i update the hashmap in the second loop. I add the Mainbeans in the below way.
Iterator<String> itr = bean_by_id.keySet().iterator(); while(itr.hasNext()){ result.add(bean_by_id.get(itr.next())); ); }

Comment: Hi Swati. I edited the code to add only when creating new instance of Mainbean. Your solution may works but have an additional loop, and you could use the valueSet() method to directly have iterator over values instead of keys.

Answer (score 2):

An idea would be to use mergesort's merge procedure. So, you first sort both lists, then combine them into one using the conditions you've specified. The code after sorting would be (more or less):

```
i = 0;
j = 0;
while (i < m && j < n) {
  Bean b1 = firstList.get(i);
  Bean b2 = secondList.get(j);
  int id1 = b1.getID();
  int id2 = b2.getID();
  if (id1 < id2) { // id2 is bigger, get from firstList, increment i
    finalList.add(new MainBean(id1,b1.getTitle(),null);
    i++;
  } else if (id1 > id2) { // id1 is bigger, get from secondList, increment j
    finalList.add(new MainBean(id2,null,b2.getTitle()));
    j++;
  } else { // both are the same, get from both, increment both
    finalList.add(new MainBean(id1,b1.getTitle(),b2.getTitle()));
    i++;
    j++;
  }
}
while (i < m) { // take the rest of firstList
  Bean b = firstList.get(i);
  finalList.add(new MainBean(b.getID(),b.getTitle(),null));
  i++;
}
while (j < n) { // take the rest of secondList
  Bean b = secondList.get(j);
  finalList.add(new MainBean(b.getID(),null,b.getTitle()));
  j++;
}
```

note:

- m = firstList.length();
- n = secondList.length();
- I assume finalList has been initialized before doing this procedure

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a relational join, specifically a full outer join.  The two solutions posted so far are essentially two of the standard techniques that an RDBMS uses to do joins -- a merge join and a hash join.  So (a) both of those are perfectly reasonable ways to approach the problem, but (b) it raises the question whether you would be better off using a database backend and letting it do the joins for you.